# Android Studio becomes unresponsive after recording video from logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-arctic-fox

I am using the Android Studio Arctic Fox.

If I record a video from Android Studio from logcat, it becomes unresponsive. I am not able to save or cancel it. Android studio must have to force close to make it work
again.

Attaching a screenshot of the hanged video recording screen and version of android studio. [![ent[image: er image description here][1]][1]]

What's the issue?

Comment: [on Mac] Getting the same thing !! It must be a bug in Arctic Fox. As a result, A.S. needs to be force closed

Comment: and saving screenshots is also borked, not just video !

Comment: despite the recent patch, this is still broken on Mac

Comment: I also tried an older version of A.S. (I keep two) and that is broke too now